# Comparing two date values in RobotFramework

Tags: datetime, robotframework

I'm trying to compare two date values using conditional statement. My plan is to validate DueDate against CompletionDate and determine if the value of CompletionDate is greater than DueDate which is not valid date value. Tried different resolution but didn't work for my desired result.

```
Test Date
    ${a}    Convert Date    12/30/2023    result_format=%Y/%m/%d    date_format=%m/%d/%Y
    ${b}    Convert Date    12/16/2022    result_format=%Y/%m/%d    date_format=%m/%d/%Y
    IF     ${a} > ${b} 
        Log To Console    A:${a} is greater than B:${b}
    ELSE
        Log To Console    B:${b} is greater than A:${a}
    END
```

The result is ${b}

My conclusion here is that the IF condition here is treating the date values differently

Is there any way to do this, I have browse already in the RobotFramework documentation but nothing fits to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think RF tries to do arithmetic on your dates. You can test this by trying date `1/1/2022'. There are two workarounds:

1. Put quotes around variables: `IF     '${a}' > '${b}'`
2. Convert dates to epoch: `result_format=epoch`

Here is a code sample:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    DateTime

*** Variables ***
${a_date}    12/30/2023
${b_date}    12/16/2022

*** Test Cases ***
Test Date with Epoch
    ${a_epoch}    Convert Date    ${a_date}    result_format=epoch    date_format=%m/%d/%Y
    ${b_epoch}    Convert Date    ${b_date}    result_format=epoch    date_format=%m/%d/%Y
    IF     ${a_epoch} > ${b_epoch}
        Log To Console    \nA:${a_epoch} is greater than B:${b_epoch}
    ELSE
        Log To Console    \nB:${b_epoch} is greater than A:${b_epoch}
        Fail   A should be greater than B
    END

Test Date with String
    ${a_str}    Convert Date    ${a_date}    result_format=%Y/%m/%d    date_format=%m/%d/%Y
    ${b_str}    Convert Date    ${b_date}    result_format=%Y/%m/%d    date_format=%m/%d/%Y
    IF     '${a_str}' > '${b_str}'
        Log To Console    \nA:${a_str} is greater than B:${b_str}
    ELSE
        Log To Console    \nB:${b_str} is greater than A:${b_str}
        Fail   A should be greater than B
    END
```

Comment: Hi @Pekka, I already tried to use putting quotes before, that doesn't fix my issue. What I have done is change the result_format to "%Y%m%d" and let the conditional statement treat those dates as integer and that works fine for me. I don't know if this is the proper way lol. But I would upvote the idea of using the epoch for now. Thanks a lot!